# amazon aws in the middle of data transfer will cost something?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm planning to transfer data from an old ftp to a www.backblaze.com/b2 bucket.

I'm considering to use [rclone](https://rclone.org/b2/) for this.

Running rclone in a aws machine. In rclone I will configure two remotes, the ftp and the b2 bucket. Then will execute something like:

```
./rclone sync ftp:/myfolder b2:/myfolder
```

Full data size goes from 100GB to 500GB.

The aws machine is on south america and I guess the ftp also, not sure about b2 bucket.

Question: Do this consumes my amazon aws network transfer? And will it cost a lot?

Comment: You missed an important info. What is the size of the data xferring?

Comment: Question update for you.

Comment: See my answer for approximate cost.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer into AWS is free. You will be charged only when you transfer data out from AWS to internet. It depends on the region and the size of the data you are transferring out. Based on 100GB to 500GB transfer, **data transfer alone** will cost you **$9 to $45**. See [Data Transfer Cost](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for more information.

[image]

Comment: I started the transfer around 30min ago. Now I watching the aws billing management console, still the same numbers there. How long it takes to see the cost there? I see around 5 GB transferred into b2 bucket.

Comment: AWS says `several times a day`. No one knows the frequency.

Comment: @helloV, you seem to be using us-east-1 prices. South America appears to be 3 times higher. Also, we typically see billing updates every 6 hours.